# Ada Encapsulated Library Project GNAT

Tags: centos, ada, dynamic-library, gnat

I'm trying to use GNAT 95 to compile a program on my computer running CENTOS 7 64-bit with the [GNAT-GPL 2015 bundle](http://libre.adacore.com). I get a compiler message that looks like this:

```
gprbuild: encapsulated library projects not supported on this platform
```

My GPR file looks like this:

```ada
with "bc.gpr";  -- Pull in the booch95 components since ada95 doesnt have collections
with "mylibrary.gpr"; -- one of my library projects

library project Registry is
    for Source_Dirs use ("src/**");
    for Object_Dir use "bin";

    for Library_Name use "registry";
    for Library_Standalone use "encapsulated";
    for Library_ALI_Dir use "lib/registry";
    for Library_Dir use "plugins";
    for Library_Kind use "dynamic";
    for Library_Interfaces use ("...");

    package Compiler is
        for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-g", "-gnat95");
    end Compiler;

    package Linker is
        for Linker_Options use ("-ldl", "-lgcov");
    end Linker;
end project;
```

The Booch Components library is a static library project. Removing the encapsulated causes Ada to throw another error about trying to mix static and dynamic libraries:

```
shared library project "registry" cannot import static library project "bc"
```

Any Idea what might be causing the Ada compiler to crash?

Comment: Must the Registry library be dynamic? What would happen  using `for Library_Kind use "static";` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you’re using a *very* old version of the BCs, you can build as a shared or dynamic library by setting the scenario variable `LIBRARY_TYPE` to `relocatable`; either by setting as an environment variable, or

```
gprbuild -XLIBRARY_TYPE=relocatable ...
```

or with GPS. I’m not a GPS user, but having investigated it seems (with GPS GPL 2014) you select *Scenario* in the tabs on the left hand side, which should show the scenario variables in your project and the projects it depends on (`bc` in your case). Select the one you want to change and click the pen icon, you get a dialog box to update it.

[image: Setting a scenario variable in GPS]

Comment: How would I add the -XLIBRARY_TYPE=relocatable argument to my gnatmake command using GPS?

Comment: Added an example of setting a scenario variable defined in a `with`ed project.

Comment: I didn't realize that there was a scenario tab in GPS.